# Spring Security ldapAuthentication always successful

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-ldap

Implementing a ldapAuthentication into my Spring Security configuration makes the process ignoring the boolean field : "enabled" on Users (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails) so it's allowing disabled Users to connect..

The Security Config works well and it disallow disabled Users to connect with a simple authentication  using userDetailsService but it fails with ldapAuthentication.

Here is **SecurityConfig** class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mykeys.test"})
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Resource
    Environment environment;
    @Resource
    BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource;

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_SECURITY_KEY = "security.key";

    @Resource(name="userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Resource
    public void configureAuthentification(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
                .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(new UserDetailsServiceLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(userDetailsService))
                .userSearchBase(environment.getProperty(LdapConfig.PROPERTY_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_BASE, LdapConfig.DEFAULT_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_BASE) )
                .contextSource(contextSource);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                     .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())

                .and()
                    .headers()
                        .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN"))
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Resource
        Environment environment;


        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/less/**", "/favicon.ico", "/holder.js/**", "/img/**", "/partial/**");
        }



        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .formLogin()
                        .permitAll()
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                        .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                        .expiredUrl("/login?error")
                    .and()
                .and()
                   .rememberMe()
                        .key(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_SECURITY_KEY, UUID.randomUUID().toString()))
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest()
                            .authenticated();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is **UserDetailsServiceImpl** class (this bean is auto injected into SecurityConfig class):

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Resource MessageSource messageSource;

    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {

            List<GrantedAuthority> list = getAllAuthor();
            org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    username,
                    username,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    list
            );

            return user;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Authentification refusée pour l'utilisateur au login {}", username, e);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getAllAuthor(){
        Collection<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add("ROLE1");
        roles.add("ROLE2");

        ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> authorities=new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        if (roles != null) {
            for (String roleName : roles) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleName));
            }
        }
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

And here is the **LdapConfig** class :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableLdapRepositories
    public class LdapConfig {

        public static final String PROPERTY_LDAP_URL = "ldap.url";
        public static final String DEFAULT_PROPERTY_LDAP_URL = "ldap://localhost:33899";

        public static final String PROPERTY_LDAP_LDIF_FILE  = "ldap.ldif";
        public static final String DEFAULT_LDAP_LDIF_FILE = "classpath:data/ldif/corp.mykeys.com.ldif";

 public static final String PROPERTY_LDAP_LOGIN_DN = "ldap.login.dn";
    public static final String DEFAULT_PROPERTY_LDAP_LOGIN_DN = "LOGIN";

    public static final String PROPERTY_LDAP_PASSWORD = "ldap.password";
    public static final String DEFAULT_PROPERTY_LDAP_PASSWORD = "pass";

        public static final String PROPERTY_LDAP_SEARCH_BASE    = "ldap.searchbase";
        public static final String DEFAULT_LDAP_SEARCH_BASE = "dc=corp,dc=mykeys,dc=com";

        public static final String PROPERTY_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_BASE   = "ldap.usersearchbase";
        public static final String DEFAULT_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_BASE = "OU=FR,OU=Employees";

        @Resource
        Environment environment;

        @Bean
        BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource() throws Exception {
            LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
            contextSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_LDAP_URL, DEFAULT_PROPERTY_LDAP_URL));
            contextSource.setBase(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_LDAP_SEARCH_BASE, DEFAULT_LDAP_SEARCH_BASE));
            contextSource.setAnonymousReadOnly(true);


            contextSource.setUserDn(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_LDAP_LOGIN_DN, DEFAULT_PROPERTY_LDAP_LOGIN_DN));
            contextSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_LDAP_PASSWORD, DEFAULT_PROPERTY_LDAP_PASSWORD));

            if (environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_LDAP_URL, DEFAULT_PROPERTY_LDAP_URL).contains("ldap://localhost")) {
                ldapServer();
            }

            return contextSource;
        }

        @Bean
        LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() throws Exception { return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
        }

        @Bean
        @Lazy
        public ApacheDSContainer ldapServer() throws Exception {
            ApacheDSContainer apacheDSContainer= new ApacheDSContainer(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_LDAP_SEARCH_BASE, DEFAULT_LDAP_SEARCH_BASE), environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_LDAP_LDIF_FILE, DEFAULT_LDAP_LDIF_FILE));
            apacheDSContainer.setPort(Integer.valueOf(DEFAULT_PROPERTY_LDAP_URL.substring(DEFAULT_PROPERTY_LDAP_URL.lastIndexOf(":")+1)));

            return apacheDSContainer;
        }

        @Bean
        public String userSearchBase() {
            return environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_BASE, DEFAULT_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_BASE);
        }

    }
```

And implementing a custom userDetailsContextMapper doesn't work too..

Comment: You can extend your search filter to `(&(enabled=TRUE)(uid={0}))` as a workaround.

Comment: The reason why `LdapAuthenticationProvider` does not check `UserDetails` flags is that this should be performed by the LDAP server during BIND request. If you are using LDAP only as a user data source and not as an actual authentication provider, use `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and implement your own `UserDetailsService` to read the user data from LDAP.

Comment: Yes this is my actual workaround.. And yes if the authentication passes LDAP, UserDetails object ignores the fields.. I'm using a double Authentication so don't need to DaoAuthenticationProvider because it will result the same combined with LDAP authentication.

Comment: Then I miss what is actually your question.